# loader in nuxt(2) build config - aws dynamodb import failing to compile

Tags: vue.js, amazon-dynamodb, nuxt.js, babel-loader

I am getting the following error when trying to compile nuxt project.
(end goal here is to try and connect to aws dynamodb from within nuxt project)

```
nuxt02  |  ERROR  in ./node_modules/@aws-sdk/util-endpoints/dist-es/lib/index.js
nuxt02  |
nuxt02  | Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:9)
nuxt02  | File was processed with these loaders:
nuxt02  |  * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
nuxt02  | You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
nuxt02  | > export * as aws from "./aws";
nuxt02  | | export * from "./booleanEquals";
nuxt02  | | export * from "./getAttr";
```

nuxt.config.js build section:

```
/*
     ** Build configuration
     */
    build: {
        /*
         * You can extend webpack config here
         * https://v2.nuxt.com/docs/features/configuration/#extend-webpack-config
         */
        extend(config, ctx) {
            if (ctx.isDev) {
                config.devtool = ctx.isClient
                    ? "source-map"
                    : "inline-source-map";
            }

            // https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/announcing-the-end-of-support-for-internet-explorer-11-in-the-aws-sdk-for-javascript-v3/
            config.module.rules.push({
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(aws-sdk|@aws-sdk)\/).*/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        //presets: ['@nuxt/babel-preset-app']
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                }
            });

        },

        babel: {
            presets({ isServer }) {
                const targets = isServer ? { node: "current" } : { ie: 11 };
                return [
                    [require.resolve("@nuxt/babel-preset-app"), { targets }]
                ];
            }
        }
    }
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "analyze": "nuxt build --analyze",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook",
    "deploy": "npm run build && sls deploy"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb": "^3.210.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^0.1.9",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.3.6",
    "@nuxtjs/gtm": "^2.3.0",
    "@nuxtjs/sentry": "^4.1.2",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^1.4.0",
    "browser-detect": "^0.2.28",
    "hooper": "^0.3.4",
    "lg-thumbnail": "^1.1.0",
    "lightgallery.js": "^1.1.3",
    "mapbox-gl": "^1.10.0",
    "nuxt": "^2.0.0",
    "nuxt-fontawesome": "^0.4.0",
    "nuxt-i18n": "^6.6.1",
    "nuxt-start": "^2.12.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "serverless-apigw-binary": "^0.4.4",
    "serverless-http": "^2.0.1",
    "v-click-outside": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-cookies": "^1.7.0",
    "vue-light-gallery": "^1.0.1",
    "vue-mapbox": "^0.4.1",
    "vue-scrollto": "^2.18.1",
    "vue-slick-carousel": "^1.0.6",
    "vue-youtube-embed": "^2.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@nuxtjs/proxy": "^1.3.3",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.3.17",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^5.3.17",
    "@storybook/addons": "^5.3.17",
    "@storybook/vue": "^5.3.17",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-preset-vue": "^2.0.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "serverless-domain-manager": "^3.2.1",
    "serverless-offline": "^4.10.0",
    "serverless-plugin-warmup": "^4.9.0"
  }
}
```